# How to know whole collection is indexed or not in mongodb river

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

i am using mongoDB 2.4.8,elastic search 0.90.10 and river 1.7.4.Using oplog of mongodb, river index documents in mapped collection. i have 20,00,000 docs. It takes around 25 mins to index the whole collection. Now my prob is i cant know whole collection is indexed or not. i need to know when all index is done and process further.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about sending a [_count](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) request like below?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_count
```

Comment: yes.. i can cross check db count and index count.. let it b unanswerd to get more suggestion..!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the _status option on the Url? Also this should be logged at the info level in your elastic search logs.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/index.html#status

Comment: can u elaborate?? i cant find any useful information in that..!

Comment: perhaps you could improve your question regarding what you want to achieve. Two people have provided you with answers on how to tell if an indexing process is still running and where the current document count is standing at. If these answers are not what you want then you need to be more specific to your goal.